# Can I claim tax relief for money I spend at the dentist?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, tax-deduction, medical-bill

(I apologize if the terminology I use is not appropriate, but finance is a topic I'm definitely not into. And I'm not native English speaker. For instance, I used the term *relief* because that's what I understand is the correct term, but please correct me if I'm wrong. Likewise, I've added [tax-deduction](/questions/tagged/tax-deduction) because it seems relevant from the description.)

In short,

- I've been to the dentist and paid 90£
- I have the receipt (actually in two parts, because I paid 40£ in advance and 50£ right after the treatment)

can I do anything to claim back some money?

In Italy it's common to keep receipts whenever we pay money to a doctor, because we can then attach all those receipts to a "declaration" that ultimately helps us save money.

Comment: Your question seem perfectly understandable to an American...

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm relieved :D

Answer (score 4):

No, in the U.K. unless you have bought dental insurance then there is no way to claim that money back or deduct it from any kind of tax.

If you sign up for private dental insurance then you pay a monthly fee and can submit the receipts to the insurer for a partial refund.